# C free and struct

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, free

My question is about C free() function for deallocating memory blocks previously allocated with malloc().
If i have a struct data type compose of several pointers, each of them pointing to different memory locations, what would happen to those memory locations if i apply free() on the struct? will that locations be free too? or just the memory block that allocate the pointer?

Comment: Just to augment the answers below, if you just free the struct, you'll have what's called a memory leak (unless you have other pointers to that memory)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. They won't be freed. You have to free them "manually". The malloc knows nothing about the content of your struct (it does not know it is a struct at all, it is just a "piece of memory" from its point of view).

Comment: I presume you mean "it does *not* know..."

Answer (score 9):

If you only free the struct, memory pointed to by pointers inside the struct won't be freed (assuming it was mallocd). You should free them first.

You can use valgrind (if available) to see for yourself:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct resources{
   int * aint;
   double * adouble;
};                                                                              
int main(){

   int* someint = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1024);
   double* somedouble = malloc(sizeof(double)* 1024);

   struct resources *r  = malloc(sizeof(struct resources));

   r->aint = someint;
   r->adouble = somedouble;

   free (r);
   return 0;

}

$ gcc test_struct.c -o test
$ valgrind ./test
==9192== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9192== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9192== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9192== Command: ./test
==9192== 
==9192== 
==9192== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9192==     in use at exit: 12,288 bytes in 2 blocks
==9192==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 12,296 bytes allocated
==9192== 
==9192== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9192==    definitely lost: 12,288 bytes in 2 blocks
==9192==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9192==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9192==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9192==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9192== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==9192== 
==9192== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9192== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 7)
```

Comment: ...and adding `free (someint); free (somedouble);` at the bottom of `main()` (before `return`) fixes the leaks, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Node
{
  struct Node *nextSibling;
  struct Node *prevSibling;
  struct Node *parentNode;
  ...
};
...
struct Node *rootNode;
/* Initialize `rootNode' and fill in its various fields;
   do the same with more nodes.  */
```

If you use `free(rootNode)`, it will only free the memory of that single node.  In other words, you'll have a bunch of memory allocated that you won't be able to free unless you free it before freeing the memory used by the node you actually want to delete.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'd love more explanation there, because I just ran into this exact issue.  Could you explain why I couldn't free the siblings AFTER I'd freed the root node?

Comment: Assuming you still hold pointers to the siblings, you may free them. For example if you did `struct Node *prev = rootNode->prevSibling;`, you could free `prev` after freeing the root node. Otherwise, you have a "dangling pointer", which is a memory leak. You can't free the root then the siblings because the address the root points may have had its value overwritten, so what you think is a sibling may be something else.If you must free the siblings later, make sure you can still access those addresses somehow. Otherwise you will leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify on @Chrono Kitsune's answer, it'd still be possible to free the pointers inside of the struct, but it's risky.

What `free(rootNode)` does is actually tell the memory management unit that the memory space that was being used by `rootNode` is not being used anymore and is fair game for anything else that needs it. Though, `rootNode` still points to the same location, it's now considered an invalid pointer, and its contents may by corrupted because its location can now be overwritten by other things.

If you try to access `rootNode` right after freeing it, it *might* work, but there's no guarantee, so it's safest to `free` its contents (that have been `malloc`'d) *before* deleteing `rootNode` itself.